# Implement row-level security as a user table or millions of roles?

Tags: postgresql, security, role, row-level-security

PostgresSQL 10.4 is our backend database for a consumer-facing app with millions of users. When implementing row-level security so each user can only access their own data, is it best practice to use a separate Postgres role for each user or to have a shared role with a user table?

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createpolicy.html) always uses examples with separate Postgres roles, whereas e.g. [this blog](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/application-users-vs-row-level-security/) describes how to do it using a user table.

Answer (score 2):

With that many users, it's probably only practical to manage it using a shared role with your own user table. In fact, I know of very few consumer-facing applications that manage their users using database roles. The thing is, you almost certainly need to store more information per user than what Postgres stores for roles. So if you just manage your users as data in your own table, you're done. But if you have to create a role for each user too, then you're increasing the work you need to do. So I'd stick with a user table.